# communication between threads in java

Tags: multithreading, communication

I have Java server for the device communication with that server.
when a particular device requests server creates a separate thread with the unique name this name will never change.

I have many threads at a same time at the server. 
All of the threads have unique names and when a
thread get destroys again when the request 
will arrive from the device at server again

the thread will be created with the same name. 
and I want a static buffer in which I could write 
data for a particular thread so that when again at server it is created it can read that particular data.

Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do your devices pass any information (a name ? a mac address ?) to your server ?
If the information is unique, then use that as you unique identifier.

If you are able to uniquely identify a device by some information that they provide, then you have a unique id.

If the information that makes a device unique is too 'bulky' to use as a thread-name (or contains characters that cannot be used to name a thread) then use a HASH algorithm (SHA1? MD5?) to create a (nearly) unique ID instead.